# how to change tinymce textarea text color

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to change the text color for tinymce text editor, when I type text inside it is by default appearing with gray color, I want text to appear with say red color. I think I will have to override its default css not sure about it, any suggestions?

Comment: ok got it, yes need to change/override the tinymce  skin specific css

Comment: no, this is a bad idea - see my answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible don't fiddle with the tinymce skin specifics.
Best practice is to use the tinymce configuration parameter [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css).

```
content_css : "http://path_to_css/custom_content.css",
```